# How to parse a Json object for the desired objects

Tags: json, node.js

I am looking to parse a json url/file and get only the top nodes from the json.

The json object looks like this:

```
{
"2017080350": {
    "home": {
        "score": {
            "1": null,
            "2": null,
            "3": null,
            "4": null,
            "5": null,
            "T": null
        },
        "abbr": "ARI",
        "to": null
    },
    "away": {
        "score": {
            "1": null,
            "2": null,
            "3": null,
            "4": null,
            "5": null,
            "T": null
        },
        "abbr": "DAL",
        "to": null
    },
    "bp": 0,
    "down": null,
    "togo": null,
    "clock": null,
    "posteam": null,
    "note": null,
    "redzone": null,
    "stadium": "Tom Benson Hall of Fame Stadium",
    "media": {
        "radio": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "tv": "NBC",
        "sat": null,
        "sathd": null
    },
    "yl": null,
    "qtr": null
},
"2017080351": {
    "home": {
        "score": {
            "1": null,
            "2": null,
            "3": null,
            "4": null,
            "5": null,
            "T": null
        },
        "abbr": "ARI",
        "to": null
    },
    "away": {
        "score": {
            "1": null,
            "2": null,
            "3": null,
            "4": null,
            "5": null,
            "T": null
        },
        "abbr": "DAL",
        "to": null
    },
    "bp": 0,
    "down": null,
    "togo": null,
    "clock": null,
    "posteam": null,
    "note": null,
    "redzone": null,
    "stadium": "Tom Benson Hall of Fame Stadium",
    "media": {
        "radio": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "tv": "NBC",
        "sat": null,
        "sathd": null
    },
    "yl": null,
    "qtr": null
}
}
```

What I'm trying to get are the two values `2017080350` and `2017080351`
I can read and display the contents fine but I am having a issue when attempting to get the two mentioned nodes?

Comment: Use Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj ).

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you read the contents?

Comment: You want to get those two keys?

Comment: Your title says "objects". The first sentence of the question says "nodes". At the end of the post you say "values". Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response is not yet parsed, then first do:

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

And then you could use a `for...in` loop:

```
for (let key in response) {
     console.log(key);
}
```

To read the data linked to the key, you would expand like this:

```
for (let key in response) {
     console.log(key);
     let value = response[key];
     // and you can go deeper...
     for (let deeperKey in value) {
         // ...etc.
     }
}
```